# Nonnegativity assumption for the Schwarz rearrangement of a function

Tags: measure-theory, spectral-theory, decreasing-rearrangements

I recently tried to understand the proof of Faber-Krahn inequality and stumbled upon the Schwarz rearrangement. For example, (See, for example, [Henrot's book "Extremum Problems for Eigenvalues of Elliptic Operators", Chapter 2, page 17](https://books.google.com/books?id=8GXrQNw2SjYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)) There, he define the Schwarz rearrangement $u^*$ of a nonnegative measurable function $u$ on a measurable set $\Omega$ and vanishing on the boundary $\partial\Omega$. It can be shown that

1) The $L^p$ norm remains unchanged, i.e. $\|u\|_p = \|u^*\|_p$.

2) We have the Polya inequality, which states that if $u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, then $u^*\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ and 
$$ \|\nabla u^*\|_{p,\Omega^*}\le \|\nabla u\|_{p,\Omega} $$
where $\Omega^*$ is the Schwarz rearrangement of $\Omega$ and $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ the Sobolev space.

Two questions:

1) Can we still define Schwarz rearrangement of any measurable function, without the nonnegativity assumption?

2) If the answer to Q1 is positive, then does it mean that the two results I quote above fail to hold without the nonnegativity assumption? If so, can someone provide a counter-example?

Comment: It's true that $\| |u|^* \|_p = \| u \|_p $ but I don't know what can be done for the Polya inequality.

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks. Apparently Polya-Szego inequality is a deep result.

Comment: In the Remark 2.3.5, p. 40  from the book S. Kesavan - Symmetrization & applications-World Scientific (2006) it is said the these properties you mentioned are true for a function which can be negative or change its sign. However, the rearrangement used is a little different, I mean, it is for a function in $\mathbb{R}^N$ vanishing in the infinite.